# How to detect android phone rotation in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, rotation, gyroscope

In my Unity app, I would like to detect, if an android phone with landscape orientation is tilted up or down - for example like here: https://lh3.ggpht.com/A-9UCSQn7nujEMF5qmJir2YKIHbu3ehFneELSXprBBId_TYhVONTCd3guPUgQ-qte6GO=h900-rw

Rotation vector sensor is probably the tool, which I am  looking for, but I did not find how can I access it with Unity. 
I don't want it to be dependent on the speed, I just need to know, if the phone is facing a floor or a sky.

How can I detect the rotation?

Comment: Can you clarify what rotation your looking for?  Are you just looking for the phone's orientation?  Or if you hold the phone out in front of you in landscape orientation do you want to know if it is tipped down and up?

Comment: Do you need the angle of the device toward the sky/ground or just a binary - Its down/Its up? – David 1 hour ago

Comment: I added the Component code to my answer.  Please let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest ways to achieve that is with Input.deviceOrientation.

```
if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait)
```

or

```
if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft)
```

you can also check for:
Unknown, Portrait, PortraitUpsideDown, LandscapeLeft, LandscapeRight, FaceUp and FaceDown.

Have a look at:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html

Comment: This won't work since deviceOrientation() will tell you if the phone's left side or right side is facing up but the OP wants to know if the phone is ""facing the sky or floor"

Comment: @David You can use DeviceOrientation.FaceUp and DeviceOrientation.FaceDown

Comment: Ah, yes, right but it will depends on if @Yerdno wants a binary up/down or if he wants the elevation angle of the phone...  Trying to clarify with a comment to Yerdno

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to use Gyroscope.attitude

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update() {
        transform.rotation = Input.gyro.attitude;
    }
}
```

ref :https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gyroscope-attitude.html

Answer (score 0):

As @Demon mentioned you need to use Input.gyro.attitude but there are a few things you need to be mindful of:

#1 Make sure the device has a gyroscope:

```
if (!SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
{
    // Exit with message
}
```

#2 Make sure you enable the Gyroscope

```
Input.gyro.enabled = true;
```

#3 Convert from the gyroscopes right-hand coordinate system to Unity's left-hand coordinate system:

```
    private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
    {
        return new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
    }
```

*** Edit ***

Here's the component to get the direction the phone is tilted:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Orientation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text textComponent;
    public GameObject blockText;
    Gyroscope gyro;
    float initAng;

    const float angTolerance = 20;

    Quaternion gyroCalibration;
    void Start()
    {
        // Make sure device supprts Gyroscope
        if (!SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope) throw new Exception("Device does not support Gyroscopoe");

        gyro = Input.gyro;
        gyro.enabled = true;    // Must enable the gyroscope

        textComponent = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
        blockText = GameObject.Find("Block Text");

        Quaternion attitude = Attitude();
        initAng = Elevation(attitude);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        Quaternion attitude = Attitude();
        float ang = Elevation(attitude) - initAng;

        String dirStr;
        if (ang < -angTolerance)
           dirStr = "Down";
        else if (ang > angTolerance)
            dirStr = "Up";
        else
            dirStr = "Center";

        textComponent.text = ang.ToString() + "\n" + dirStr;    // +ang = up   -ang = down
    }

    private Quaternion Attitude()
    {
        Quaternion rawAttitude = gyro.attitude;             // Get the phones attitude in phone space
        Quaternion attitude = GyroToUnity(rawAttitude);     // Convert phone space to Unity space

        return attitude;
    }

    private static Quaternion GyroToUnity(Quaternion q)
    {
        return Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0) * new Quaternion(q.x, q.y, -q.z, -q.w);
    }

    private static float Elevation(Quaternion attitude)
    {
        Vector3 dir = attitude * Vector3.forward;           // Convert Quaterinon to Dir
        Vector2 horizontalDir = new Vector2(dir.x, dir.z);
        float horizontalDis = horizontalDir.magnitude;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(dir.y, horizontalDis) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;  // Calculate the elevation

        return ang;
    }
}
```

You could just use 'deviceOrientation()' but there are two advantages to doing it this way:

#1 You have control over how far you need to tilt the phone for it to register a tilt were using deviceOrientation you have to tilt the phone very far before it registers a tilt

#2 It uses the device starting elevation as a reference which compensates for a user that either holds the phone slightly down or up in general